# Search and cut in mp3 every spoken word of an audio file automatically

Tags: audio, mp3, diff, speech-recognition, cut

First I am going to broadly state what I'm trying to do and ask for advice. Then I will explain my current approach and ask for answers to my current problems.

**Problem**

I have an MP3 file of a person who speaks in English is a story in podcast. I'd like to split it up into segments roughly corresponding to a word. (I would do it manually, but we are talking about hours of data that I would have to cut or separate).

If you have advice on how to do this automatically, I would love to hear it.

**Current Approach**

I can only cut with Audacity manually.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off your question doesn't have anything to do with MP3 or whatever codec it's in to start with.  To do any meaningful processing, you'll have to convert it to a regular PCM stream.  FFmpeg is great for this, but there are plenty of other tools for MP3.

Next, I recommend looking into speech recognition libraries.  Stripping one down into its bare components might give you word boundaries.

This problem isn't as simple as looking for quieter points in the audio and making a cut.  Most folks when speaking will do so in a continuous breath and sound, with articulation controlling airflow and sound output from there.  This is especially the case with professionals.  You'll need something that's aware of the context of what's being spoken, which is why I think that a speech recognition library might be a good place to start.